# What are all the rupas of devi to manifest in us according to devi stotra?

Tags: scripture, devi, stotra

For many days, I am aware of stotra of the form

> Ya Devi sarva bhuteshu "____"-rupena samsthitha ; Namastasye
> Namastasye Namastasye Namo Namaha

When I search about it I came [across the following](https://www.artofliving.org/wisdom/wssst/significance-of-devi-stotra) to fill the portion provided

1. Buddhi
2. Nidra
3. Kshudha
4. Chhaya
5. Shakti
6. Trishna
7. kshanti
8. Jaati
9. Lajja
10. Shanti
11. Shraddha
12. Kaanti
13. Lakshmi
14. Vritti
15. Smriti
16. Daya
17. Pushti
18. Maatru
19. Bhranti

So, there is a total of 19 qualities have been mentioned in the Devi stotra.

I want to know whether they are complete. I mean, are there any other qualities that we can fill in the blank provided in accordance with the scriptures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the part of famous Tantrokta Devi Suktam that is part of Durga Saptasati that is part of Devi Mahatmya of Markandeya Purana. This suktam was sung by Devas when they were defeated by Shumbha and Nishumbha. The whole stotra is little bit larger than that of `ya devi sarva bhuteshu` part but it mention only the 22 qualities of Devi.

Although everything is manifestation of Devi but this stotra mention those 22.

[Markandeya Purana, Devi Mahatmya, Chapter 82](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/markandeya-purana/chapter-82/topic-1)

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु बुद्धिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ १४॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Intellect, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to ber, reverence, you reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु निद्रारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः।। १५ ।।

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of sleep, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु क्षुधारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ १६ ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Hunger, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु छायारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः।। १७ ।।

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Shadow, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु शक्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ १८ ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Energy, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु तृष्णारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ १९ ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Thirst, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु क्षान्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २०॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Patience, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु जातिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २१॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Speciality, Reverence to ber, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु लज्जारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २२ ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Modesty, Reverence to her yea.reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverencet

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु शान्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २३॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Peaceableness, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> देवी सर्वभूतेषु श्रद्धरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २४

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Faith, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु कान्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥२५॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Loveliness, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु लक्ष्मीरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥२६॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Good Fortune, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु प्रतिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २७॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Holding. Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! to Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु वृत्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ २८ ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Activity. Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु स्मृतिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३० ॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Memory, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु नीतिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३१॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Moral behaviour.
> Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु तुष्टिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३२॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Contentment. Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु पुष्टिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३३॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Thriving. Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु दयारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३४॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Mercy, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!2

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु मातृरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३५॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Mother. Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!

> या देवी सर्वभूतेषु भ्रान्तिरूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः॥ ३६॥

> To the goddess who among all created beings Stands firm with the form of Error, Reverence to her, yea reverence to her! Reverence to her, reverence, yea reverence!