# What are the scriptural meanings or definitions of the following qualities mentioned in devi stotram?

Tags: devi, stotra, inner-meaning

The [following qualities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50136/what-are-all-the-rupas-of-devi-to-manifest-in-us-according-to-devi-stotra) are mentioned in devi stotra.

> Buddhi, Nidra, Kshudha, Chhaya, Shakti, Trishna,
> kshanti, Jaati, Lajja, Shanti, Shraddha, Kaanti, Lakshmi, Vritti, Smriti, Daya, Pushti, Maatru, Bhranti.

The meanings that are given in [this source](https://www.artofliving.org/wisdom/wssst/significance-of-devi-stotra) for them are as follows:

1. Buddhi - intellect
2. Nidra - Sleep
3. **Kshudha - hunger**
4. **Chhaya - Shadow**
5. Shakti - energy
6. **Trishna- thirst**
7. **kshanti- restlessness (frustration)**
8. Jaati - (multitude of )species
9. Lajja - shyness
10. Shanti - peace
11. Shraddha - faith
12. Kaanti - radiance, shine and brilliance
13. Lakshmi - beauty, abundance and prosperity
14. **Vritti - thoughts**
15. Smriti - Memory
16. Daya - compassion
17. Pushti - contentment
18. Maatru - motherliness
19. **Bhranti - confusion**

The words mentioned here have several meanings with scriptural interpretations. The provided meanings in the English language may not be apt to describe those scriptural meanings.

I want to know the scriptural meanings/interpretations for the words I bolded in the list.
Suppose Vritti can be taken as the work/profession done a person daily: like studying for a student. But, I don't know whether it is apt in the context.

What are the scriptural meanings for the bolded forms?